# Why does a user require the "Manage Flows" permission to run a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I built a flow that sends multiple records for approval at once. It's triggered by a list button. You select items from the related list that the button is on, click the button, and the flow runs in the background, submitting selected records for approval. When it's done running, it takes the user back to the parent record's page.

As an admin, I can use the button to trigger the flow without any issues. When I log in as a user with a "Run Flow" permission on their profile and click the button, I get the "insufficient privileges" error. Checking the "Flow User" box on the user record doesn't make a difference. When I add the "Manage Flows" permission to the profile, I am able to run the flow as that user (i.e., it works as expected).

The fact that the "Manage Flows" elevated permission (normally reserved for admins) is needed is a problem because some of the users who need to use the button are on the Chatter Plus license. Their profiles don't even have the "Manage Flows" permission available (but they do have "Run Flow").

- Running the flow in system context without sharing doesn't make a difference.
- There are no custom components in the flow.
- When debugging the flow as the end user, it doesn't show any errors: https://www.screencast.com/t/zwHV2tCpkZ
- The checkbox "Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets" on the Edit Access page is not checked.
- The flow and the approval process are active.
- The user has full CRED to both the child and the parent, including any fields being updated by the approval process.

My only guess for why elevated privileges are needed is because the flow leverages the obscure "ids" variable (described here: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EB8jQAG).

Does anyone have any other ideas on what the issue might be, and if there are any solutions and if not, workarounds (even if it means using code)? A huge thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the approval process setup? Is the user you're using allowed to submit for approval per the [Initial Submitters](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.approvals_create_submitters.htm&type=5) setting?

Comment: Kris, thank you so much for your fast response! The initial submitters are Record Creator and Parent Record Owner. The objects are in a M-D relationship, we are submitting the children for approval en masse. The end-user in question is is the owner of the parent.

I created a screen flow triggered by an action button on the child. There's just one screen that displays the record ID, and the next node is the "submit for approval" action. This way, the user is able to submit a singular record for approval, even without the "Manage Flows" permission.

Comment: got it, sounds like you did a lot of the steps for troubleshooting +1. Are you on a Winter '22 org? If you updated your flow to do nothing (no variables, etc) - does the error still show for that user?

Comment: Yes, Winter 22. I don't think I can update the actual flow not to use the "ids" variable, it's the only way (that I know of) to pass multiple record IDs. To troubleshoot, I built a flow on the child: https://www.screencast.com/t/UMvIiHWGlsY. It's triggered by an action button.

Screen element: https://www.screencast.com/t/KlyKrCSI. Submit for Approval element: https://www.screencast.com/t/HKJucbGx0 (it's identical to the one in the original flow). Variable that passes the record ID to the flow: https://www.screencast.com/t/vuQwxifOyxW

No errors for the end-user with this flow.

Comment: I just meant removing `ids` to see if the error goes away (not as a permanent change) through the list view button. You can have an empty flow (with a blank screen) to see if the issue is just clicking any flow on the list view (considering they can run a flow in the other way you tested). Otherwise, a case might be the best option or inspecting the network tab to see if you can see anything else to point to an error.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try these things. I will do my best to remember to post an update when/if I solve this (or if I won't). Thank you again for sharing your time and expertise!

Comment: Kris, I just figured out that it was a sad mistake on my part. 

The button was referencing the version of the flow with a different name than the one I thought was running. The two flows are identical, save for their names. I deactivated the original flow, but forgot to reference the new flow name in the button. Since the two flows were identical, everything was still working when I used the button linked to the old flow (as an admin, I have the Manage Flows permission allowing to run inactive flows). That's why the end-user got the error when using the flow unless they had "Manage Flows."

Comment: Always worth answering your own question (and accepting it) as you never know if someone else might stumble upon it and save themselves from a similar situation.